# Limit cfinput to valid currency values

Tags: regex, validation, coldfusion

My regex-fu is not as good as it should be.

I am merely trying to limit a `cfinput` to valid currency (dollar) values.

Here is what I'm (unsuccessfully) using:

```
<cfinput 
  id="currency1" 
  maxlength="9" 
  style="text-align:right;" 
  name="currency1" 
  value="#numberFormat(variables.currency1)#"
  onchange="updateTotal(this,this.form.currency2,this.form.totalAmt);"
  type="text" 
  validate="regular_expression" 
  pattern="/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/" 
  size="9" 
  validateAt="onblur" 
/>
```

I'm currently getting a syntax error with IE 8, but I tried the same form with Firefox/Firebug and can't get it to throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could the `(?: )` syntax for the non-capturing group be causing a problem here?  What if you try

```
  pattern="/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/"
```

Alternatively if that still causes errors in IE, here's an alternative

```
  pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/"
```